# How to use ffmpeg to fix mp4 videos that only have sound from right ear?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a bunch of `.mp4` videos that only the right ear has sound. Is it possible to make the video have two channels so that I can hear the same sound from both left and right ears? Thanks.

Here is an example of such video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdKgeeb4q3w&list=PLbxFfU5GKZz1Tm_9RR5M_uvdOXpJJ8LC3&index=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the channelmap filter to replicate the right channel.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -af "channelmap=FR-FL|FR-FR" -c:v copy out.mp4
```

Comment: Hi Gyan, I tried the command and the resulting video has no sound from both sides. The resulting video size is 284MB and the original size is 291MB. Any ideas? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: This is the log: https://i.imgur.com/pG82WFN.png

Comment: Edited cmd.....

Comment: This works! Thank you so much Gyan.

Comment: That didn't work for me but this did: https://superuser.com/a/1602830/920897