# Add filter to one audio channel using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, audio, ffmpeg

Having stereo audio files where sound is only in left channel. (Recorded in stereo with input only on left channel.)

I am sourcing left channel to right by using the pan audio filter.

```
ffplay -i sample.wav -af "pan=stereo|c0=c0|c1=c0"
```

which works fine. But there is a lot of noise etc. that I am working on fine-tuning using things like `afftdn` as well as `anequalizer`, compressor and so on.

**My question is how I can apply filters to *one channel only*.**

Something like:

- Left channel => noise cancelling filter ++
- Right channel => untouched source

Reason being I want to easier listen to the *“effect of the effects”* on left channel compared to the original sound. Optionally outputting *two* audio tracks, where I then can cycle by using <kbd>a</kbd> in `ffplay`. As in:

- Audio track 1: filter
- Audio track 2: raw

But not sure if that is possible with `ffplay`.

---

I am listening to this by using `ffplay` and testing using `azmq` to tune the filters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ffmpeg Audio Stereo to Mono using only left channel](https://superuser.com/questions/702552/ffmpeg-audio-stereo-to-mono-using-only-left-channel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would clone the source, apply filters to one copy and then merge.

`asplit=2[left][right];[left]filters...[left];[left][right]amerge=inputs=2`

In case of complaints by amerge about channel layouts, use

`asplit=2[left][right];[left]filters...,channelmap=0[left];[right]channelmap=0[right];[left][right]amerge=inputs=2`

Comment: Edited answer..

Comment: Works well. Now I realize using two audio tracks would be better, heh. Wrap it in some container where I can switch between *raw* and *with-filter*, - but that would be another question.